# Coding a discrete fourier transform on python WITHOUT using built in functions

Tags: python, fft, dft

Here's what I have

```
import math
import numpy as np
from cmath import sqrt

# Ask the user for the number of elements in the sequence
n = int(input("n: "))

# create a matrix full of n elements
x = [0]*n
for i in range(0,n):
    x[i] = int(input(f"x{i}: "))

j= sqrt(-1)

y = [0]*n
for k in range(0,n):
    for l in range(0,n):
        y[k] += x[l]*(np.exp((-np.pi *j* k*2)/n))

# Print out the answers
for i in range(0,n):
print(f"y{i} = {y[i]}")
```

## **Example 1**

The answers I get when I use `x = {0,1,2,3}` is:

```
y0 = (6+0j)
y1 = (3.6739403974420594e-16-6j) WRONG
y2 = (-6-7.347880794884119e-16j) WRONG
y3 = (-1.102182119232618e-15+6j) WRONG
```

It should be: `6, -2+2j, -2, -2-2j` as partially derived here:
[image]

## **Example 2**

If n is 2 and `x = {1,2}`

Then the expected answers are: `3/sqrt(2)` and `-1/sqrt(2)`

## **Example 3**`

if n is 4 and `x = {1,1,0,0}`

Then the answers are `2`, `1-j`, `0` and `1+j`

---

Here's a fix, yet when I do the `x={1,2}` part, I don't get the theoretical answers... They are very different

```
import math
import numpy as np
from cmath import sqrt
n = int(input("n: "))

x = [0]*n

#Create a matrix for n amount of inputs
for i in range(0,n):
    x[i] = int(input(f"x{i}: "))

#Empty matrix for the answers for later

y = [0]*n
# define j so that it can be used later
j = sqrt(-1)
for k in range(0,n):
    for l in range(0,n):
        # Carry out the summation
        y[k] += x[l]*(np.exp((-np.pi *j*l* k*2)/n))

for i in range(0,n):
    print(f"y{i} = {y[i]}")
```

Comment: Your expression `np.exp((-np.pi *j* k*2)/n)` is missing a multiplication by `l`.

Comment: Fixed, but I dont get the same answers for x={1,2}

import math
import numpy as np
from cmath import sqrt
n = int(input("n: "))

x = [0]*n

#Create a matrix for n amount of inputs
for i in range(0,n):
    x[i] = int(input(f"x{i}: "))

#Empty matrix for the answers for later

y = [0]*n
# define j so that it can be used later
j = sqrt(-1)
for k in range(0,n):
    for l in range(0,n):
        # Carry out the summation
        y[k] += x[l]*(np.exp((-np.pi *j*l* k*2)/n))

for i in range(0,n):
    print(f"y{i} = {y[i]}")

Comment: I suggest you use any FFT implementation to double-check your expected outcome. `fft(1,2,3,4)` is `10` for `k=0` (the sum of the values: 1+2+3+4=10). `fft(1,2)` is `(3,-1)`, no `sqrt(2)` involved.

Comment: the solution is as mentioned by @CrisLuengo here is the missing 'l'. As for the wrong answers incase of x={1,2} they are correct 3 and -1. You can use this https://www.easycalculation.com/engineering/mechanical/discrete-fourier-transform.php to see your answers. There is no factor of sqrt(2) in denominator :)

Comment: Or just compare to the result of `np.fft.fft()`.

Answer (score 0):

A much faster method to get the DFT `X` of a sample sequence `xn` of length `N` is to use [the concise matrix form of the DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix). It is easily implemented with a numpy array and the `matmul` product function:

```
# Custom matrix
import numpy as np
k = np.arange(N)
M = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k[:, None] * k / N)
X = np.matmul(xn, M)
```

The python `for` loops are replaced by [faster C loops internal to numpy](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html) and possibly vectorization features of the CPU.

There is a scipy function, named `dft` which returns the same array, so you can save one line of code:

```
# Built-in matrix
import scipy.linalg as sl
M = sl.dft(N)
X = np.matmul(xn, M)
```

The next piece of code shows the perfect matching these methods and FFT:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_peak_frequencies(ax, ff):
    lims = ax.get_xlim()
    tax = ax.twiny()
    ticks = np.hstack([-ff, ff])
    tax.set_xticks(ticks)
    tax.set_xlim(lims)
    tax.grid()

mag = lambda X: abs(sf.fftshift(X))
omega = lambda f: 2*np.pi * f

# Sampling parameters
N = 70
fs = 10
Ts = 1 / fs
max_t = (N-1) * Ts

# Signal components
ff = np.array([1, 2.5, 3.5]) # frequencies Hz
w1, w2, w3 = omega(ff)

# Continuous signal
t = np.linspace(0, max_t, 200)
x = lambda t: 2 * np.cos(w1*t) + np.cos(w2*t) + 0.5 * np.cos(w3*t)
xt = x(t)

# Actual samples
n = np.arange(N)
xn = x(n*Ts)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, squeeze=True, figsize=(9, 3), layout='constrained')

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t, xt, c='gray')
ax.stem(n*Ts, xn)
ax.set_title(f'Signal sampled at {1/Ts:0.2f}Hz')
ax.set_xlabel('t (s)')

# Built-in fft
import scipy.fft as sf
X1 = sf.fft(xn)
f = sf.fftfreq(N, Ts)
f = sf.fftshift(f)

# Built-in matrix
import scipy.linalg as sl
M2 = sl.dft(N)
X2 = np.matmul(xn, M2)

# Custom matrix
k = np.arange(N)
M3 = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k[:, None] * k / N)
X3 = np.matmul(xn, M3)

ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(f, mag(X1), label='FFT', c='lime', lw=7, alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(f, mag(X2), label='scipy matrix', c='navy', lw=4, ls='--')
ax.plot(f, mag(X3), label='custom matrix', c='magenta')
show_peak_frequencies(ax, ff)
ax.set_xlabel('f (Hz)')
ax.legend()
```